# Nginx redirect to another directory but index page

Tags: nginx

I am trying to do the following nginx redirect

```
/news/today-xx/index.php (xx will be moving with new page)
/blog/category-xx/today-xx/index.php
```

to

```
/article/today-xx/ (xx will be moving with new page)
/article/category-xx/today-xx/
```

but still want to access archival pages.

```
/news/index.php and /news/
/blog/index.php and /blog/
```

Here is what I have so far

```
 location ^~ /(news|blog)/(.*) {
    return 301 /article/$1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
location ~ ^/(news|blog)/(.+)/index\.php$ {
    return 301 /article/$1;
}
```

I added the starting and ending anchors (`^` and `$`), escaped the extension for php (`\.`) and most importantly, changed the middle section to `(.+)`, which captures one or more characters between the slashes to the variable. This means that the regex won't match to the old archive scripts.